# XML encoding for '#'

Tags: xml, spring, encoding, character-encoding, apache-camel

I'm trying to configure this in spring/camel xml:

```
<c:from uri="mina:upd://localhost:6060?codec=#myCodec&amp;sync=false" />
```

so i get this excpetion

> Unrecognised MINA protocol: upd for uri:
>   mina://upd://localhost:6060?codec=%23myCodec&sync=false

See: **%23**

I already tried `&#23;` and `&#x23;` but it does not work.

Obs: My file is UTF-8 and i declare

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Any idea?

Comment: can you urldecode the codec variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The protocol should be "udp" I think.